# Display text or table based on ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a table that is populated based on API call response(`job_list`). If no data is returned, I want to display a text saying "No data". I have done the following:

##### HTML

```html
<div [hidden]="!job_list.length">
<table>
.
.
.
.
.
</table>
```

Where should I add the text "No data"? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via a separate template, all it just requires is one `*ngIf`, with an `else` included. [Read more about ngIf in the official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="job_list.length; else noDataTemplate">
    <table>

    </table>
</ng-container>


<ng-template #noDataTemplate>
    <p>No data found</p>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check.

```
 <div *ngIf="job_list.length > 0">
   // Show table
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="job_list.length === 0">No Data</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[ngSwitch]** to achieve this. More info in [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase)

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="job_list.length">
   <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="0">
      <p>No Data</p>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
      <table>
    
      </table>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Try it yourself on [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4cce5v?file=src/app/app.component.html)